# convert DB:table query to eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a method in my controller where I return an array of books from a database like so:

```
$books= DB::table('books')->where('category_id', $category_id)->orderBy('title', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```

Now I want to be able to use an eloquent relationship with the resulting array of books like this in my view:

```
@foreach($books as $book)
    <p>Title: {!! $book->title !!}
    <p>Category: {!! $book->category() !!}
@endforeach
```

From my understanding this will not work because the $books array is not in Eloquent. How can I make it so it does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already have `Book` and `category` model and both have relationship to each other

Try this:

```
$books= Book::with('category')->orderBy('title', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```